# Best way to copy all properties from different class under different package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two classes, C1 & C2, inside different package.

```
package p1
class C1 {}

package p2
class C2 {
  C1 abc;--> refer to class C1 in package p1
  int i;
  String s
}
```

`-----------

```
package p3
class C1 {}

package p4
class C2 {
  C1 abc; --> refer to class C1 in package p3
  int i;
}
```

Let's assume some fields in p4.C2 class is missing but it is there in p2.C2. What is the best way to copy all values from p2.C2 to p4.C2?
Fields that are missing in p4.C2 should be ignored while copying.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is not related to Spring and it's a general Java question.

Make all your classes **public** so that they are accessible from outside the package. And if you want `C1` class properties should available in `C2` then follow the below code.

```
import P1.*;
class C2 extends C1
{
....
}
```

In this way, all the properties of class `C1` will be available to class `C2`. You can follow same step for class `C3` and `C4`.

Comment: I can't modify any of the classes

Comment: then as per my knowledge, you can't do that. If you get an answer let me know.